# How to fix second header row in kableextra

Tags: r, scroll, header, kableextra

Taking example code from this guide:[1](https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_html.html#HTML_Only_Features)

```
kbl(cbind(mtcars, mtcars)) %>%
  add_header_above(c("a" = 5, "b" = 18)) %>%
  kable_paper() %>%
  scroll_box(width = "100%", height = "200px")  %>%
  kable_styling(fixed_thead = T)
```

How can I keep the added additional header fixed? The original header is fixed but I would like the additional header to be fixed as well. The fixed_thead =T code does not make this work.

Please advise. Thanks in advance!